# Vertx Socket Hang Up while using async aws Route53AsyncClient

Tags: aws-sdk, vert.x

I have a vertx application which is using aws Route53AsyncClient sdk to get data. I am getting socket hang up in postman whenever this sdk call takes 5 secs or more. Is there any timeout that needs to be configured since it is async (java completable future)

Comment: Also the log shows the request got processed successfully but client receives socket hang up in postman and curl: (52) Empty reply from server in terminal

Comment: are you sending the response back? Share a snippet of the code - nobody can help you like this

Comment: yes i am sending the response back. I am getting the response if the aws call takes less than 5 sec but in case it takes more time the postman gives socket hang up and in terminal the curl gives --> curl: (52) Empty reply from server in terminal. The server log shows the request was processed properly